# DebugView suddenly stops working

Tags: debugging, winapi, debugview

Has anyone encountered a situation where DebugView application suddenly stops working, e.g. there is an application that calls DebugOutputString Win32 API but the output stops appearing in the DebugView application window? Can it be caused by high load of messages? any other pathological condition?

We don't know if DebugView crashes or just stops receiving messages. The application and debugview are installed on customer machine with no direct access. We just see that DebugView output stop exactly before the customer experiences the problem (not connected to debugview). And it is frighteningly consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was DebugView running out of memory. User Ctrl-H to limit the window size.

I think DebugView should be improved to put some indication that it cannot allocate memory any more and put it to log file.